# tiny-dnn example breaks on training, when using 2 classes instead of 10

Tags: tiny-dnn

I'm very new to tiny-dnn. This [example](https://github.com/tiny-dnn/tiny-dnn/blob/master/docs/how_tos/How-Tos.md#sequential-model) works fine with my data:

```
net << convolutional_layer(32, 32, 5, 1, 6) << tanh() // 32x32in, conv5x5
    << average_pooling_layer(28, 28, 6, 2) << tanh()  // 28x28in, pool2x2
    << fully_connected_layer(14 * 14 * 6, 120) << tanh()
    << fully_connected_layer(120, 10);
```

When I try to reduce the output to my actual number of classes 2 - the example breaks. It is the oly change between working and not working code - 10 changed by 2. Is 2 a special number for classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found th reason. I've enumerated the classes starting from 1 - 1,2. There is an assertion checking the number of classes. The number of classes should be greater then the last class id. 
After renaming the class IDs to 0,1 instead of 1,2 everything works.